# Use PHP to create an Email list

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

I'm trying to create an email list. I have tried it a dozen different ways. My last attempt makes the most sense to me, but it seems to ONLY send to the last person on the list, and no one else. Am I doing something wrong or should I just go about a different way of doing this? When I view the page, it posts "Mail sent." for every user on the list, though the email actually only sends to the very last person on the list.

```
<?php include '../../manage.php'; include '../../sql.php';

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email_list=1";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"$sql");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

$to = $row[email];
$subject = "Quote Requested";
$message = "Testing.";
$from = "email@mydomain.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";

}
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($to);` in every `while` iteration

Comment: @u_mulder that just printed out the following: string(27) "email1@domain.com" Mail Sent.string(24) "email2@domain.com" Mail Sent. but it still only sent to the last person. I placed `var_dump($to);` right underneath `$to = $row[email];` was that the correct place to put it?

Comment: I have literally just tested the whole code posted, only creating my own connection string ie `$con` using the manuals example `$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));`. I created a database with 5 entries, 3 of which were `email_list` 1. I see absolutely no issue and received three emails. My only thought is potentially to globalise the `$con` variable.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat I looked into it, and out of all the users on the list, the only one that was receiving the email was an email address that wasn't apart of our organization. Outlook was filtering the email to junk mail automatically, even though it was coming from an organizational address. Had to set it not to filter junk mail at all for it to work. Thanks for your help with testing it!

Comment: @StauntonAllen glad to be of help. Looks like we both learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

First, two things you should fix:

```
$to = $row[email];
```

should be

```
$to = $row['email'];
```

Also, you should not be using the mysql_* functions, because they are deprecated and have been deprecated for a long time now.  Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

For your problem, you should do this:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    echo "Mail Sent to ".$to;
} else {
    echo "Mail Failed to Send to ".$to;
}
```

It is saying "Mail Sent" each time because there's nothing stopping it when failures occur.

Comment: I wouldn't use `echo "Mail Sent to ".$to;` should there be hundreds, if not thousands of Emails in DB. It's best to maybe use some form of a `foreach` (looped) counter to show how many in a "number" were sent. P.s.: I'm NOT a downvoter, should it happen. Some think that, whenever someone posts a comment in an answer that gets downvoted, immediately think it's "that" person in question that did. ;-) (I've seen that happen quite often). However, you may be right about `$to = $row['email'];` but many times, arrays should not contain quotes. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am definitely right about putting quotes around string keys.  If you leave it without quotes, it is an undefined constant `email` assumed to evaluate to the string 'email', which means it only works because PHP tries to auto-correct mistakes.  As for the echoing, he's already printing out "Mail Sent" every time.  Might as well put actual useful information in those echoes.  I'm sure he'll figure out some better way of keeping track of such things eventually.

Comment: I believe you're right also. The echoing part should be done outside the loop, for sure.